# FullCalendar integrated with HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, fullcalendar

Has anyone successfully integrated [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) with [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)?

Currently I display data in a monthly view using text. I would like to replace them with pie charts generated by the HighCharts js library.

The FullCalendar uses a EventSource to load the events. I send JSON serialized data from my `MVC controller`. To enable HTML in the Event Title I use [the solution mentioned here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=152)

I tried using the [DotNet.HighCharts library](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) and returning the `chart.ToHtmlString()` as the event title, but I keep getting the js error below:

```
Unhandled exception at line 117, column 483 in 
    /Scripts/Highcharts-2.3.5/js/highcharts.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: 
    Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. The problem was with the DotNet.HighCharts library. The chart script that is was returning (chart.ToHtmlString()) had issues with the latest version of the HighCharts JS scripts. Instead I removed the DotNet.HighCharts library and constructed the Chart JS script in my controller and it works fine.